# Zend - Selecting a specific field

Tags: php, zend-framework, select, join

I'm trying to query a database to find the results of one specific field in a table. The following code, from all the reserach I've done, should return only the 'id_maquina' field but it's actually returning all fields.

```
$hist_select=$historico->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('t1'=>'maquina_cafe'),array('t1.id_maquina'))
    ->joinLeft(array('t2'=>'maquinas'),'t1.id_maquina=t2.ID')
    ->where('t1.username = ?',$identity);
```

I added the *array('t1.id_maquina')* to the from method to specify that as the field I want as instructed in a post here on stackoverflow but it's not working. Anyone has any thoughts on what is wrong with this?

Comment: Post the results of `echo $hist_select;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Zend version do you use?

You select all Columns form the joined table, because '*' (all columns) is default for the join.

Try:

```
$hist_select=$historico->select()
                      ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                      ->from(array('t1'=>'maquina_cafe'),array('t1.id_maquina'))
                      ->joinLeft(array('t2'=>'maquinas'),'t1.id_maquina=t2.ID', array())
                      ->where('t1.username = ?',$identity);
```

Comment: To answer your question, I am using Zend 1.12 and your suggestion worked. I was using join but added the joinLeft exactly to prevent the return of any field from the right table. Thank you very much.